# Coreservice client to 8.5 from 7.1 and cannot use the getCurrentUsers methods

Tags: core-service

Recently I upgraded my Tridion coreservice client to 8.5 from 7.1 and then I am not able to use the some basic methods like `client.Read()` , `client.GetCurrentUser` etc which gives us exception error:

> Method Read is not supported on this proxy, this can happen if the
>   method is not marked with OperationContractAttribute or if the
>   interface type is not marked with ServiceContractAttribute.

Comment: Have you recompiled the code against the new DLLs?

Comment: Note that if you decide to use another version of the Core Service Client, you are implicitly using another Core Service Contract. Therefore, you should ensure you also use another Core Service endpoint URL, otherwise you will get errors about a contract mismatch.  That’s a different error than what you are mentioning, though.

Comment: How can we change the Endpoint URL for the new coreservice?
Actually im triying to develop an Alchemy plugin so i didnt use any endpoint